# Clicking on button in windows 10 via python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I used win32com to read and send an outlook mail, but when i do it creates a pop up which asks me to deny or allow the program to do so, there is a python module which will allow me to press "allow for 10 minutes," and then click allow?

Just wanted to know if there a module which is able to do so similar to what selenium does on web

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
It's called [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and it does Native GUI automation for Windows.
To get the id's of the UI you're trying to automate, use what Microsoft recommends: [Accessiblity Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/).

Answer (score 0):

You get a standard security prompt in Outlook.

There are several ways for suppressing such prompts:

1. Use a third-party components for suppressing Outlook security warnings. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.
2. Use a low-level API instead of OOM. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API, for example, [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption).
3. Develop a COM add-in which has access to the trusted Application object.
4. Use group policy objects for setting up machines to avoid security prompts.
5. Install any AV application with the latest updates.